# xPath oddity where predicates are somehow necessary

Tags: xslt, xpath

This may seem like an odd question as I did find a working solution, but can anyone tell me why my first xPath below works and the second one does not? I did include the enes namespace in my XSLT.

Solution A works:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document('my_document_of_citations.xml')//node()[namespace-uri()='enes' and local-name()='section' and position() = $section-pos]/node()[namespace-uri()='enes' and local-name()='litref']" />
```

Solution B does not work:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document('my_document_of_citations.xml')//enes:section[position() = $section-pos]/enes:litref" />
```

Here is the stylesheet, with only the code in a non-germain template and function omitted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="enes thieme xhtml xlink xs" version="2.0" xmlns:enes="http://www.thieme.de/enes" xmlns:thieme="http://www.thieme.de/enes" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:func="enesfunc">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.1" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<!-- Identity Transform -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="part[@type eq 'content']/section[@level eq '1']">
    <xsl:element name="section" xmlns="enes">
        <xsl:attribute name="level" select="1" />
        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="./@id"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="counter"><xsl:value-of select="./@counter"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
        <!-- Insert a level 2 section with the references for this level 1 section from references_by_chapter.xml here. -->
        <xsl:element name="section" xmlns="enes">
            <xsl:attribute name="level" select="2" />
            <xsl:attribute name="type">
                <xsl:text>literature</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>

            <!-- Get the absolute position of this section within the document. -->
            <xsl:variable name="section-pos" select="count(./preceding-sibling::section) + count(ancestor::node()/preceding-sibling::node()[local-name() eq 'part']/node()[local-name() eq 'section']) + 1" />

            <!-- Copy extracted references from xml here -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="document('references_by_chapter.xml')//node()[namespace-uri()='enes' and local-name()='section' and position() = $section-pos]/node()[namespace-uri()='enes' and local-name()='litref']" />
            <!-- <xsl:copy-of select="document('references_by_chapter.xml')//enes:section[position() = $section-pos]/enes:litref" /> -->
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section[@level eq '2']//text()">
    <!-- code to transform level 2 sections here. -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="func:myStrFunc">
    <!-- more code here. -->
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: My guess would be your `enes` prefix was bound to a different uri, but it's impossible to tell without the input XML and the XSLT (at least the part that shows the namespace declaration).

Comment: Well, my XML looked like this:

<document xmlns="http://www.thieme.de/enes" language="en-US">
   <section xmlns="enes"> 

with the attribute xmlns="enes" appearing in every section node. When I removed it the simpler solution worked.

Thanks, Daniel.

Comment: @kalinma Would you be so kind and edit the input document into your question? Also, your question really is only complete if you also add a _complete_ XSLT stylesheet with which people can reproduce your problem.

Comment: I agree with Mathias, if you add the XSLT we can tell you exactly what was wrong. Removing the namespace from the input XML shouldn't be considered an answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying the code to remove irrelevant detail, consider

```
child::x[position()=2]
```

versus

```
child::*[name()='x' and position()=2]
```

The meaning of these two constructs is quite different. The first expression considers all the child elements whose name is 'x', and then returns the second of these. The second construct considers all the child elements, and then selects the second child provided that its name is 'x'.

Which of these "works" depends of course on what your requirements are. Both of them are correct, they just do different things.

Comment: Oddly enough, this works, even using name() instead local-name():

    <xsl:copy-of select="document('references_by_chapter.xml')//node()[name()='section' and position() = $section-pos]/node()[name()='litref']" />

while this does not work:

    <xsl:copy-of select="document('references_by_chapter.xml')//child::section[position() = $section-pos]/child::litref" />

I'm beginning to wonder if the problem here is with the XSLT parser.

Comment: Why do you consider it odd that these two expressions produce different results? I thought I had explained why that is what you should expect.